# error: failed to remove /Users/gs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData - “Info.plist” couldn’t be removed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I’ve hit a problem working on iOS app development using Xcode outside Australia. Yesterday I was using Xcode inflight to compile and build the app and again for a short time upon arriving in Mumbai. The moment I removed an obsolete source file that was no longer needed in the app - i.e. just removing the reference and not deleting the file - I started getting compiler and linker problems.

The first message said my developer’s license had expired on March 27. But as I had used Xcode successfully on a daily basis since that date I assumed the problem might be related to Xcode being licensed only for use within Australia.

I logged onto the Apple Developers site where I agreed to accept terms and conditions and found no indication that my license had expired. So I restored the obsolete file and deep cleaned (command+option+shift+K) and rebuilt the project and now have multiple Dependency Analysis Warnings

**Showing All Issues**

```
error: failed to remove /Users/gs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-ehpokmdvcmvspodonmckmjkbbfzj/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/xxx.app/Info.plist: “Info.plist” couldn’t be removed.
```

**Showing All Issues**

```
: error: couldn't remove '/Users/gs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-ehpokmdvcmvspodonmckmjkbbfzj/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/xxx.app/Info.plist' after command failed: No such file or directory

Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'Info.plist'.
```

and multiple of the next warning

```
    Warning: Multiple build commands for output file /Users/gs/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SatGam-ehpokmdvcmvspodonmckmjkbbfzj/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/xxx.app/xxx.ipa
```

with the following files

```
    xxx.app/xxx.mobileprovision
    xxx.app/HelpText.xcf
    xxx.app/ios_distribution.cer
    xxx.app/PhoneDeviceID.txt
    xxx.app/iOS Human Interface Guidelines: Icon and Image Sizes.pdf
    xxx.app/AppleWWDRCA.cer
```

and two that I wouldn't expect to be part of an Xcode project

```
    xxx.app/ios_development.cer
    xxx.app/HelpText.xcf
```

*(I attended AppleWWD in 2009. The GIMP project file was used to create .PNG assets in 2013)*

I’ve repeated the deep clean procedure, closed Xcode, rebooted the simulator (hoping to erase any old versions from the simulator) but I can’t get rid of the problem. The multiple build commands suggest that Xcode is getting confused keeping track of old versions of the app.

Does anyone have any suggestions how I can restore Xcode to good health ?

Comment: What is your OS and xcode version ?

Comment: iOS10.4 and Xcode 8.3.1. The project was started with iOS4.

Comment: I mean what is your Mac OS version ??

Comment: Abhishek, it's 10.12.4

Comment: Have you re-added that obsolete file again, which you had been removed its reference from your project?

Comment: Abhishek, thanks, I found the problem. See my answer.

Comment: I glad that you made that..

Answer (score 2):

My problem was solved once I understood and trusted what Xcode was saying. By selecting the target in the navigation window, I found many `Info.plist` files from earlier versions of my project. I carefully removed all but the latest version but still the project would not compile.

Then in the navigation window I discovered groups containing every file from earlier versions of my project. While I had made backups of my project I most certainly had not created groups within the project so I can only assume Xcode did this as it tried to make sense of backup copies I had made. There was even a project file in each group that allowed me to build and run earlier versions of the project successfully. Once I removed all references to these file groups from the navigation window, I was able to compile the latest version of the project successfully.